# GraphQL-tools: How do I write resolver function to search a list?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-tools

I'm just learning GraphQL, and am struggling on the return statement in a resolver function. All I want is to search for an item by ID.

My search:

```
query {
  link(id: "link-0") {
    url
  }
}
```

I keep getting this error: `"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Link.url."`

I think the issue is in my `map` function `return` statement, but I've tried with `links.find()` and other ways and just can't get it to work.

```
let links = [
    {
        id: "link-0",
        url: 'www.gmail.com',
        description: 'Mail inbox',
    },
    {
        id: 'link-1',
        url: 'www.google.com',
        description: 'Search engine',
    },
];

type Query {
    info: String!
    feed: [Link!]!
    link(id: ID!): Link!
}

type Link {
    id: ID!
    description: String!
    url: String!
}

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        feed: () => links,
        link: (parent, args) => links.map(link => {
            if (link.id == args.id) {
                return link;
            }
        }),
    },
}
```

Comment: write more explicit function ... get/filter/collect value, console.log it (to check shape), return at the end

Comment: Just tried it and it seems to work! But is this the right way to do it? Feels like using [0] is a hack-y approach. ```link: (parent, args) => {
            return links.filter((link) => link.id === args.id)[0];
        }```

Comment: ... use `find()` ?